# How to generate a new genesis tx?

Tags: genesisblock, monero-forks

I did a Monero fork and i added to it a code to generate for me a new genesis tx with the knowed command `--print-genesis-tx` and it works great at start, it generates something like this `013c01ff000180cab5ee01029b2e4c0281c0b02e7c53291a94d1d0cbff8883f8024f5142ee494ffbbd08807121015b6c9c53d57e60a1283edfba1d2a6510c922f351d86c7f537de64082fdb76110` but if a try to do a solo mining i get this:

`strat_mining <address>`


`2017-07-23 16:27:52.542 [miner 0]   ERROR   cn  src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_core.cpp:917 mined block failed verification
2017-07-23 16:27:52.561 [miner 0]   INFO    global  src/cryptonote_basic/miner.cpp:456  Found block for difficulty: 1
2017-07-23 16:27:52.561 [miner 0]   ERROR   verify  src/cryptonote_core/blockchain.cpp:3164 Block with id is INVALID: <b89cd1e533c067989f52f3dc38f3b14fed297f3b20a2c9a0910e31bcdb9e4092>`

I want to premine my own cryptocurrency so the first block is 0 and the next is the max amount. But i think it isn't the problem, I think the problem is the genesis that i create.

Comment: That information is correct. But for some reason to this day.. no one has been able to get the Genesis to print out like they say... And if they had? There is only silence ad to the solution required.
To replace the Genesis with the printed one.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it changing this line from 1 to 0.

`your_coin/CMakeLists.txt:102
 # set this to 0 if per-block checkpoint needs to be disabled
 set(PER_BLOCK_CHECKPOINT 0)`

It means that before I was running my coin with checkpoints when it does not should have because is a new blockchain.

Comment: Once the blockchain has been established and the Gensis block has been created, do you need to reverse the changes to CMakeLists.txt and re build?