# error first running new monero fork build

Tags: monerod, mining, monero-forks, genesisblock

I built a new Monero Fork. Trying to run it for the first time and getting errors:

> 2018-07-05
>   10:09:30.989  7612    ERROR   cn  src/cryptonote_basic/cryptonote_format_utils.cpp:167    Failed
>   to parse transaction from blob
>
> 2018-07-05
>   10:09:30.989  7612    ERROR   default src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_tx_utils.cpp:650 failed
>   to parse coinbase tx from hard coded blob
>
> 2018-07-05
>   10:09:30.989  7612    ERROR   blockchain  src/cryptonote_core/blockchain.cpp:409  Failed
>   to add genesis block to blockchain
>
> 2018-07-05 10:09:30.989   7612    INFO
>     global  src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_core.cpp:525 Loading
>   checkpoints
>
> 2018-07-05 10:09:31.305   7612    WARN
>     blockchain.db.lmdb  src/blockchain_db/lmdb/db_lmdb.cpp:74   batch
>   transactions not enabled
>
> 2018-07-05
>   10:09:31.305  7612    FATAL   daemon  src/daemon/daemon.cpp:194   Uncaught
>   exception! batch transactions not enabled

How can I fix this?

Comment: and then what it still does NOT work

Answer (score 0):

See answer here: [How to generate a new genesis tx?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/5650/how-to-generate-a-new-genesis-tx?rq=1)

> your_coin/CMakeLists.txt:102
>
> set this to 0 if per-block checkpoint
>
> needs to be disabled  set(PER_BLOCK_CHECKPOINT 0)